# How do I get data between midnight today and NOW?

Tags: sql, oracle

As the title suggests, I'm simply trying to get the result set between midnight today and right now. So given the time of this post, I want data between 06/30/16 00:00:00 and 06/30/16 15:52:00. Why does the below query not return anything? Thanks.

```
SELECT * FROM tableName
WHERE event_date >= TO_DATE(TRUNC(SYSDATE) || ' 00:00:00', 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS')
AND event_date <= TO_DATE(TRUNC(SYSDATE))
```

Comment: just do event_date<=sysdate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM   tableName
WHERE  event_date BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) AND SYSDATE;
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName
WHERE event_date >= TO_DATE(TRUNC(SYSDATE))
```

I had forgotten that **TRUNC(**SYSDATE**)** by itself is perceived as midnight unless otherwise specified, so this does the trick.

Comment: `TRUNC(SYSDATE)` is already a date - if you use `TO_DATE()` on it then Oracle will implicitly cast the truncated `SYSDATE` to a string using the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter as the format mask and then will pass this string to `TO_DATE()` to convert it back to a date (again using the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` as the format mask).

Comment: `SYSDATE` is not midnight of the current day - it is the current server time (including hours, minutes and seconds). Also, if there are results after the current time then this will return all rows from today and in the future.

Comment: What does TRUNC(SYSDATE) return?

Comment: `TRUNC(date_value)` (with a single `DATE` argument) takes the date passed in and truncates it so that the hours, minutes and seconds are zero (i.e. midnight of the same day) and returns that date. So `TRUNC(SYSDATE)` will return a `DATE` set to midnight of the current day the server is on.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I meant. I'll edit my post above to make it more clear.